Why do we say $E=hf$ supports particle nature of light?
It is well known that the energy of light is given by $E=hf=hc/\lambda$, which supports the particle nature of light. However, $f$ (frequency) and $\lambda$ (wavelength) are properties of a wave! Isn't this contradictory? What evidence it gives about particle nature of light?

That's nothing special about the photon. Schoedinger's equation tells us that massive particles like electrons, protons, neutrons, etc., also behave as if they have a wavelength.

Photon is best described as a very localized (small in visible but huge in radio spectrum) wave in the EM field. Your textbook is based on the 1930s. Treating as a particle is fine in some cases because the photons occur one at a time. Every photon is created by an electron in an atom and every photon will eventually be absorbed by an electron in the atom.


which supports the particle nature of light.

In fact, it doesn't. First, Planck's law is not only about this mathematical relation, but it includes a discretization process.
The density of modes per unit of frequency is $8\pi f^2/c^3$. If we consider equipartition theorem that says that each mode has average energy $E_f = k_bT$ in equilibrium, we get Rayleigh-Jeans law
$$
\mu(f,T) = {8\pi f^2\over c^3}k_bT
$$
If we only postulate $E_f = hf$ for the energy of the modes, we should multiply it by Gibbs factor $e^{-hf/k_bT}$ (to get an expression for average energy) and we get
$$
\mu(f,T) = {8\pi h f^3\over c^3} e^{-hf/k_bT}
$$
Which was Wien approximation for the Black body radiation. Neither of these correctly explain the black body radiation. Only after we consider that each mode access discrete levels of energy $E_{n,f}= nhf$, and get the average energy per mode $\bar{E}_f = hf {1\over e^{hf/k_bT}-1}$, that we recover Planck's law
$$
\mu(f,T) = {8\pi h f^3\over c^3} {1\over e^{hf/k_bT}-1}
$$

Planck's law needs a different statistics to be explained, which was the first evidence of the quantum of light. I recommend you the Anti-photon paper by W.Lamb Jr. for a historical perspective about the Photon's discovery (I should say that it is  biased by his personal opinions, but it is a reliable source).

Will read more of your answers/explanations

To further point out differences, and in addition to the answer @Ruffolo gave, it's important to notice that the energy density of electromagnetic radiation in classical theory is independent of frequency. The energy density follows
$$u_{\mathrm{EM}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{D}+\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{H} \right). $$
In other words, the intensity of electromagnetic waves goes as $I\propto |\mathbf{E}|^2$. There can be variations with time in this intensity (assuming we do not take the average, which would be what you usually detect) that go as $\omega t$, but this is different from it depending on the frequency itself. This at the very least would imply that photons cannot behave merely as classical waves.
